# Using parent component class to set on different element in Vue

Tags: vue.js

Using parent component class to set on different element in Vue. How to move this class prop to any other element in the component? I am using vue 3

// component Parent

```
<ParentCompy title="hello" class="someClassName">
```

// parentCompy component

```
<template>
    <nav>// not here
        <ul class="nav nav--tabs someClassName">// but here
            <li>some list</li>
             ...
        </ul>
    </nav>  
</template>
```

Comment: which vue version are you using?

Comment: 3, forgot to mention that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to make a prop and then place it at the desired location

```
<template>
    <nav>
        <ul :class="class">
            <li>some list</li>
             ...
        </ul>
    </nav>  
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        class: String
    }
}
</script>
```

If you want to move all props automatically to this element you can [Disable Attribute Inheritance](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-attrs.html#disabling-attribute-inheritance):

```
<template>
    <nav>
        <ul v-bind="$attrs">
            <li>some list</li>
             ...
        </ul>
    </nav>  
</template>

<script>
export default {
    inheritAttrs: false,
}
</script>
```

## Edit

You can just use it like that:

```
<template>
    <nav>
        <ul class="nav nav--tabs" :class="class">
            <li>some list</li>
             ...
        </ul>
    </nav>  
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        class: String
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: How stupid of me, thanks. Also when using already set classes how can I use this (see my edited example)

Comment: Many thanks. I tried to use :class="['nav nav--tabs', class]" but this seems not to work in this example